# Present Value Calculator php

Tags: php, loops

The PHP script captures the values and calculates the future value. working backwards from the last month to the first, how could I compute the investment for the previous month  and display the months number and the value all the way back to the first investment (Unknown).  I've already figured out that I'll have to uses a formula like this "months value = (months value)/(1 + rate)" but after that I hit a road block. basically I'm trying how to figure how much do you invest today to have a balance value of $XXX after  xx years at a x% interest rate?

```
<?php
    // get the data from the form
    $investment = $_POST['investment'];
    $interest_rate = $_POST['interest_rate'];
    $years = $_POST['years'];

    // calculate the future value
    $future_value = $investment;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $years; $i++) {
        $future_value = ($future_value + ($future_value * $interest_rate *.01));
    }
    // apply currency and percent formatting
    $investment_f = '$'.number_format($investment, 2);
    $yearly_rate_f = $interest_rate.'%';
    $future_value_f = '$'.number_format($future_value, 2);

?>
```

Comment: Are you attempting to create an algorithm to find the future value? Or are you given an amount of today, and trying to find out the value that was x months ago? Also, do you need to know all of the months values in between?

Comment: I think I found other [people with the same homework](https://www.google.com/search?q="$investment%20=%20$_POST['investment'];")

Comment: I'm trying to find the later,your given the amount of today, and trying to find out the value that was x months ago and yes it should echo the values for each month in between.

Comment: basically something that looks like this The final investment is 45, the number of years are 1, and the interest rate is 2% .
At 11 month/s the investment is 44.12
At 10 month/s the investment is 43.25
At 9 month/s the investment is 42.4
At 8 month/s the investment is 41.57
At 7 month/s the investment is 40.75
At 6 month/s the investment is 39.95
At 5 month/s the investment is 39.17
At 4 month/s the investment is 38.4
At 3 month/s the investment is 37.65
At 2 month/s the investment is 36.91
At 1 month/s the investment is 36.19
Today you need to invest 35.48

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is basically this:

- Start with X
- For each of the Y years, increase X by Z%

This is a simple function: result = X * (1+Z%)^Y

So you know there's a specific result you want, and you know the number of years and the interest rate, and you want to calculate the base amount. Easy: X = result / (1+Z%) ^ Y

Using your variable names, you'd get
`$investment = $future_value / pow(1+$interest_rate/100,$years);`

Done!

Comment: how would I be able to get to the starting investment, like this: The final investment is 45, the number of years are 1, and the interest rate is 2% .
At 11 month-44.12
At 10 month-43.25
At 9 month- 42.4
At 8 month- 41.57
At 7 month- 40.75
At 6 month- 39.95
At 5 month- 39.17
At 4 month- 38.4
At 3 month- 37.65
At 2 month- 36.91
At 1 month- 36.19
Today you need to invest 35.48

Comment: Just apply the formula: 45 / 1.02 ^ 12 = 35.48